I don't understand this criticism of my code for comparing the byte-content of files
I asked for some review of the code below the other day. It's code I'm working on to compare the byte-content of files suspected to be identical; it should work with files of any file-type and any file-size. This picture shows a part of one person's criticism of it.
I'd like some help understanding this particular criticism as I don't understand it at all. I can't make head or tail of it honestly: for one thing, I can't even tell whether the indented part sub-headed as "3" is supposed to lead into the rest of it — why is the rest of it not indented similarly if so?
They seem to think using read(byte[]) is wrong to do, but I just can't understand at all their reasoning for that; I don't know why they're talking about read(byte[]) returning a value, when I thought that method was simply transferring bytes from the BufferedInputStream to the byte[] — I wouldn't have thought it to be returning anything at all otherwise — ; and I don't know where they're getting the int len1 and int len2 variables from. I can't see how they relate to the code in question at all.
To be clear, I'm not asking for a review of the given code here, it's not ready for that yet. I'm just asking for an explanation of this person's criticism of it, so that I can understand what they thought was wrong with it.
I've yet to decide on what I'll use for the break-condition for the While-Loop; there are a few different alternatives for me to consider for that. I'm not asking for help for that part here—I'm just pointing it out for the sake of clarity.
I'm also aware that there are existing methods available for comparing the byte-content of files, I don't need any help with those.
bin_1 = new BufferedInputStream(file_input_stream_1); 
bin_2 = new BufferedInputStream(file_input_stream_2);

byte[] barr_1 = new byte[8192];
byte[] barr_2 = new byte[8192]; 

while(/*enter break-condition of your choice*/){

    bin_1.read(barr_1); bin_2.read(barr_2);

    if(Arrays.equals(barr_1, barr_2) == false){
        break;
    }

    else{
        /*Byte-Arrays are Re-Assigned to ensure that no bytes from the previous loop 
          carry-over.*/
        barr_1 = new byte[8192]; 
        barr_2 = new byte[8192];
        continue;

    }
    
}


for one thing, I can't even tell whether the indented part sub-headed as "3" is supposed to lead into the rest of it  Not sure if I understand your phrasing, but yes, that's one answer, they're giving you an example that might fix the issue.  The indentation just looks like a minor error in formatting.

I don't know why they're talking about read(byte[]) Read the documentation: Returns: The number of characters read, or -1 if the end of the stream has been reached https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F22%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/io/Reader.html#read(char%5B%5D)

where they're getting the int len1 and int len2 Basically they're referring to the lengths of the arrays barr_1 and barr_2.  Those arrays might be of different lengths (or at least have different amounts of data read) and you need to save the values that read() returns and only check the valid portions of the array.

This is going to be a bit harsh, but I'll try to say it plainly.  You need to stop assuming that you know what a method does ("thought that method was simply transferring bytes") and actually read the documentation.  Files are tricky enough that finding some examples online would also help.  But to learn Java you'll need to put some more effort in, just sort of guessing at what API methods do won't work.

Worth knowing before reinventing the wheel

You're using a BufferedInputStream, which already uses a buffer of precisely the size you allocate: (private static int DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 8192;) Those bytes are already in memory, so an individual read() operation is going to have negligible overhead and (pseudo-code) f1.read() == f2.read() obviates the problems being discussed about reading into your own buffer and makes the whole thing a lot simpler. Having said that, what @Holger said above me very much applies (which is why I upvoted him)

"... one person's criticism ... help understanding this particular criticism" - wouldn't it be most appropriate to ask that person? ||| Please also check Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? (also regards to "any other textual data relevant to the question.")

Post text here rather than images, wherever practical.

"Reinventing the wheel" – a check on existing patents shows that there are more patents on wheels than on any other machine. And sometimes "reinventing the wheel" on yourself helps to understand the programming language better … when done right, of course.

@Holger Do you know if that mismatch() method can be used on all file-types. And also whether the size of the file affects it at all: i.e., does it work on very large files just as well as small ones?

@william that method has no problem that your code could solve.

This is basically saying the same thing as the other answers, but I wanted to explain the problem in more detail.
Let’s look at one of your reads:
bin_1.read(barr_1);

When that line is executed, Java SE might fill the barr_1 array, or Java might say:  “Even though you requested 8192 bytes, the operating system was only able to retrieve 4096 bytes at this time, so I’m only putting 4096 bytes in your array.”
There is no guarantee of how many bytes will be read.  It depends on the operating system, which might have allocated all of its internal buffers to other things if, for example, the system is very busy.  (It’s a lot more complex than that, of course.)
Which means it is entirely possible to have this scenario:
// Returns 8192
bin_1.read(barr_1);

// Returns 4096
bin_2.read(barr_2);

// Of course the arrays aren't equal---one of them was only partially filled!
if (Arrays.equals(barr_1, barr_1)) {

How do we know whether this happened?  By examining the int value returned by the read method.  The documentation of InputStream.read(byte[]) states:

Returns:
the total number of bytes read into the buffer, or -1 if there is no more data because the end of the stream has been reached.

(BufferedInputStream inherits that method.  The implementation may be different, but any override must, by definition, conform to the same contract laid out by the documentation.)
The easiest solution is remove your byte arrays entirely.  You don’t need them.
The arrays barr_1 and barr_2 are actually read buffers.  But, you’re already using BufferedInputStream (which is a good thing).  You don’t need to define your own buffers;  that’s what BufferedInputStream already does.
You can just read one byte at a time.  It’s not less efficient.  BufferedInputStream will take care of the efficiency.
So your loop might look like this:
int b1;
int b2;
do {
    b1 = bin_1.read();
    b2 = bin_2.read();
} while (b1 >= 0 && b2 >= 0 && b1 == b2);

// The files are identical if every byte matched, and
// the loop reached the end of both files at the same time.
boolean identical = (b1 < 0 && b2 < 0);


Thanks a lot for clearing that up. I can see how your solution deals with the scenario of each stream returning different numbers of bytes, with the && b1 == b2 clause. So b1 and b2 are ints, yet bytes are being assigned to them... so each byte (of 8 bits) is being represented as an int? Also, it's the BufferedInputStream and not the byte [] that prevents the whole huge file being read-in at once? And lastly, so it's just as much work for the system to fill those byte []s in my code as it is to call and compare bytes one-by-one from the BufferedInputStream in your solution?

You have the power to answer your own question.  Read the documentation for the InputStream.read method.  As for reading the entire file at once, it is not BufferedInputStream, specifically, but InputStream itself which allows a program to read a file (or other data source) in small pieces rather than all at once.  BufferedInputStream just happens to inherit that behavior.

BufferedInputStream already fills its own byte array (buffer).  You should not be doing work that is already done.  If you were to insist on using your own buffers (that is, byte arrays), you would want to remove the usage of BufferedInputStream, since it would be redundant.  For what it’s worth, most professional developers use BufferedInputStream to read data.


I don't know why they're talking about read(byte[]) returning a value, when I thought that method was simply transferring bytes from the BufferedInputStream to the byte[]—I wouldn't have thought it to be returning anything at all otherwise—

When in doubt what a method does, check its description. Every public method in the Java API has one, and every decent Java development environment will show it if you hover the mouse over the method call. Doing so here gives the following description:

Reads some number of bytes from the input stream and stores them into the buffer array b. The number of bytes actually read is returned as an integer. This method blocks until input data is available, end of file is detected, or an exception is thrown.
If the length of b is zero, then no bytes are read and 0 is returned; otherwise, there is an attempt to read atleast one byte. If no byte is available because the stream is at the end of the file, the value -1 is returned; otherwise, at least one byte is read and stored into b.
The first byte read is stored into element b[0], the next one into b[1], and so on. The number of bytes read is, at most, equal to the length of b. Let k be the number of bytes actually read; these bytes will be stored in elements b[0] through b[k-1], leaving elements b[k] through b[b.length-1] unaffected.

That is, your reviewer is correct that read(byte[]) may read, at its discretion, less bytes than the length of the array. And since we don't know that the two reads read equally far, the arrays may look different even if the files are identical.
Your reviewer recommends to use readNBytes(int) instead. It's description is:

Reads up to a specified number of bytes from the input stream. This method blocks until the requested number of bytes has been read, end of stream is detected, or an exception is thrown.

That is, this method promises to always read as far as the specified limit or the length of the file permits. It won't read less than that at its discretion. That is, if we read both files with this method, the arrays will only differ if the files are different.
(The reason the older method may read less bytes than requested is that this can be useful in other contexts, especially when reading from data sources that have significant latency, such as pipes or network sockets)

To avoid follow up errors: as the answer says, even readNBytes may read less bytes than requested, i.e. when reaching the end of the file. The remaining bytes in the array are unpredictable, either the initial values or the values from the previous read. So, if the files have different length, there is no guaranty that the array comparison will result in false. The arrays still may have the same content by chance.

There are two overloads for readNBytes. byte[] readNBytes(int) will return differently sized arrays. I'd recommend using that for simplicity of implementation. But of course, if one uses int readNBytes(byte[], int, int) instead, one should check that the lengths returned are equal, and not access the parts of the array that have not been filled.

But yes, I should have been clearer which overload I am talking about, thanks for the feedback @Holger.

It’s not a ‘performance optimization’ and it is certainly not ‘irrelevant nowadays’. Where do you get these ideas?

It allows the InputStream to return the bytes that are currently available (see also the InputStream.available()) without having to block until the entirety of the requested bytes have been fetched from the underlying storage. This can reduce latency in processing. It's less relevant nowadays because modern operating systems are better at prefetching when a file is read sequentially, and disk drives are more often solid state, having far less latency to begin with.

I know what it does thanks. If read() was specified to attempt to fill the buffer, network programming would be impossible.

So you are agreeing with me that this feature is "mostly irrelevant for file I/O"? Yes, the primary use is network I/O. But this question is about comparing files. Would you rather have me tell OP that incomplete reads are only for network I/O and have him assume that a FileInputStream never does that? Even though a FileInputStream's Javadoc explicitly permits incomplete reads? I think it's better advice, in particular to beginners, to rely on how the Java API is specified rather than making assumptions about how it is implemented.

I haven't said a word about file I/O. I am disputing your baseless claim that it's an 'optimization' and 'irrelevant nowadays'. These remain false. What you tell the OP is up to you, but IMHO you should just delete these statements.

read(byte[]) returns an int for how many bytes were read into the array. The critique correctly comments that

you should be checking for a return value of -1 from this function which indicates that there is no more data to read.
the way you have set this up, it is possible that a different number of bytes are read into barr_1 and barr_2 it will fail. So for example, if the entire content of the file is: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 barr_1 could read 1 2 and barr_2 could read 1 2 3 each in a single read, which would break your solution.

Additionally, creating a new byte array for each read could slam the system memory unnecessarily.
I would recommend reading from both BufferedInputStreams byte by byte instead of using an array buffer as you are doing.
Also, just FYI: There is a very nifty program called "diff" that was first built for use at the unix command line.

Reading byte by byte (without using a BufferedInputStream) is far slower than reallocating the array ...

There's an even more nifty program called cmp that just tests if two files' content is the same.  (The diff program attempts to work out what the differences are and then format them. That's more expensive.)

@meriton Good point! I have corrected to state BufferedInputStreams

Thanks a lot for your help there. Is the "diff" program available for Windows?

@StephenC Is that "cmp" program available for Windows do you know?

They will be available in a WSL environment.  The native windows equivalent is comp ... sort of.
